# pyqt5でボタンを押せないようにしたい

Tags: python, pyqt

pyqt5でボタンを押せないようにしたり、押せるようにしたいです。例えば下のコード

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5 import*

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",20)

        # ラベル名の設定
        lbl1 = QLabel('１行目')
        lbl1.setFont(font)
        lbl2 = QLabel('２行目')
        lbl2.setFont(font)
        lbl3 = QLabel('３行目')
        lbl3.setFont(font)

        self.edit1=QLineEdit()
        self.edit1.setFont(font)
        self.edit2=QLineEdit()
        self.edit2.setFont(font)
        self.edit3=QLineEdit()
        self.edit3.setFont(font)

        btn1=QPushButton("1")
        btn1.setFont(font)
        btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffcf54")
        btn2=QPushButton("2")
        btn2.setFont(font)
        btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffcf54")
        btn3=QPushButton("3")
        btn3.setFont(font)
        btn3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffcf54")

        firstlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        firstlayout.addWidget(lbl1)
        firstlayout.addWidget(self.edit1)
        firstlayout.addWidget(btn1)

        secondlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        secondlayout.addWidget(lbl2)
        secondlayout.addWidget(self.edit2)
        secondlayout.addWidget(btn2)

        thirdlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        thirdlayout.addWidget(lbl3)
        thirdlayout.addWidget(self.edit3)
        thirdlayout.addWidget(btn3)

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(firstlayout)
        layout.addLayout(secondlayout)
        layout.addLayout(thirdlayout)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Absolute')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが出来ます。
[image: 画像]
ここで、例えば一つ目のボタンを押せないようにする(押しっぱなしのような状態？)にするにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 一つ目のボタンを押せないようにする（押しっぱなしのような状態？）とはどういうことかもう少しわかりやすくできませんか？つまり、押したらずっと色が変わったように（押されているんだということが）わかるようにしてほしいということですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単に押せないようにするのであれば、`setEnabled(False)`でよいと思います。
(押せるようにするには`setEnabled(True)`です)

```
# ボタン1を押せなくする
btn1.setEnabled(False)
```

＃`QWidget`クラスのメソッドです。(`QPushButton`に継承されている)

何かの処理契機で呼びだせば画面に反映されます。

Comment: なるほど、そういう事なんですね。勉強になりました（笑）。

Comment: 素早い回答ありがとうございます！お陰様で無事解決しました。